# Windows 10 Windows Explorer Automatically Synchronize this Folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, sync

I know that you can synchronize the tree pane with the current directory for windows using the following window.

[image]

However, starting Windows 10. I cannot seem to find the new settings. It now shows this Quick Access option that does not really help. Is the feature gone in Windows 10?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Had a quick google and found the way to enable this.

1. Open an explorer window
2. Right click the empty space in the navigation pane on the left, to open the context menu
3. Click "Show all folders" and "Expand to current folder"

[image: Window pane screenshot]

Done!

Taken from [here](https://winaero.com/blog/navigation-pane-show-folders-windows-10/)